# Issues with "No Module named..."(Python) in Multi-Language Protobuf/Grpc Project

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

i have a Project containing several C# and Python Projects (Sln, csproj and pyproj). My Project uses gRPC/Protobuf for Inter-Service-Communication. It's a Microservice Architecture.

I have a folder called `_SharedProtos` at the Root containing my Protos.
The C# Part is easy and already done.
I just included it in the csproj-File using

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="..\_SharedProtos\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

For the Python-Part, i use the Command: `python -m grpcio_tools.protoc --proto_path=..\_SharedProtos\ ..\_SharedProtos\* --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=.` in my Python Project that requires the Proto-Python-Files. Let's call it MyProject.ProtoProject1
The Files are placed at: `MyProject.ProtoProject1\Protogen`

My Issue is, that i get some very inconsistent erros with "No Module named..." when referencing the Proto-Python-Files.

This are the `import` Directives that i use:

```py
import Protogen.Shared_pb2
import Protogen.Shared_pb2_grpc
import Protogen.SystemConsole_pb2
import Protogen.SystemConsole_pb2_grpc
```

This is the Error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programming\LS\Source\MyProject.ProtoProject1\Program.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Console
  File "C:\Programming\LS\Source\MyProject.ProtoProject1\Console.py", line 5, in <module>
    import Protogen.SystemConsole_pb2
  File "C:\Programming\LS\Source\MyProject.ProtoProject1\Protogen\SystemConsole_pb2.py", line 14, in <module>
    import Shared_pb2 as Shared__pb2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Shared_pb2'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is my Project's Structure

```
C:.
│   Console.py
│   MyProject.ProtoProject1.pyproj
│   Program.py
│
├───Protogen
│   │   Shared_pb2.py
│   │   Shared_pb2_grpc.py
│   │   SystemConsole_pb2.py
│   │   SystemConsole_pb2_grpc.py
```

Can some help or suggest how to re-structure this?

Answer (score 0):

Please share screenshot for correct file.
The problem is in the underlined file:[image]

Where you're trying to import Shared_pb2 as Shared_pb2.

Answer (score 0):

So i now found out what the Issue was, appearently Python didn't like the MyProject.ProtoProject1 Path. After i renamed the Directory, the issues were resolved.